Are bilaterians well-nested in Cnidaria?
From looking at articles, it seems that all the major neurotransmitters - serotonin, dopamine and noradrenaline - are present in Cnidaria. This, in addition to the fact that Cnidaria have a nervous system which uses the same neurotransmitters, would raise the question of whether Bilateria arose from within Cnidaria.
My questions are:

Does Bilateria arise from within Cnidaria in the same way that birds are dinosaurs?
If so, would cnydocytes have been ancestral in Bilateria but lost?
Do Bilateria and Cnidaria share a common ancestor that is not shared with Placozoa, Porifera and Ctenophora?
If so, was this common ancestor similar to an Anthosoa, but lacking in cnydocytes?


Bilateria are most likely not nested in Cnidaria. Peterson and Davidson, 20001 and Medina et al, 20012 discuss the developmental history of the Bilateria with respect to other groups within Animalia.
It seems most likely that Cnidaria and Bilateria share a common ancestor, which explains the common gene groupings. As such, Cnidaria is a branch of the Eumetazoan tree, as is Bilateria. This ancestor would also have been an ancestor of Ctenophora, but seemingly not of Porifera, which may have diverged before the divergence of Cilateria and Cnidaria, though this is hotly debated. The following image from Peterson and Davidson, 20001 shows their relationships based on Homeobox gene evolution:

 Image attribution: From reference 1. Note the following text from image caption: This view of Hox cluster evolution devolves from studies of de Rosa et al. (33), Finnerty and Martindale (30), and others (see text). The adult enteropneust, the larval enteropneust, and the larval sea urchin photographs are from the authors' collections; the rest of the animal pictures are from ref. 40 [reproduced with permission from ref. 40 (Copyright 1980, Stanford University Press)]
Medina et al, 20012 reached a similar conclusion using ribosomal RNA sequencing, as you can see in the following image. Note the difference between the two maximum likelihood trees; on the left is the small subunit tree and the right has the large subunit tree.

 image attribution: from reference 2.
As you can see there is some rearrangement of the order of relatedness between the Cnidaria, Ctenophora and Porifera between the two RNA types. This sort of information has led to some controversy in the literature, with some studies supporting the Porifera-first tree and some disagreeing with this, based on ever larger data-sets including more genes and more organisms, as noted in the introduction of this review by Steenwyk and King, 20243 (see  section titled The Tangled Branches in the Tree of Life).
Refs:

Peterson KJ, Davidson EH. Regulatory evolution and the origin of the bilaterians. Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A. 2000 Apr 25;97(9):4430-3. doi: 10.1073/pnas.97.9.4430. PMID: 10781037; PMCID: PMC34315.

Medina M, Collins AG, Silberman JD, Sogin ML. Evaluating hypotheses of basal animal phylogeny using complete sequences of large and small subunit rRNA. Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A. 2001 Aug 14;98(17):9707-12. doi: 10.1073/pnas.171316998. PMID: 11504944; PMCID: PMC55517.

Steenwyk JL, King N. The promise and pitfalls of synteny in phylogenomics. PLoS Biol. 2024 May 20;22(5):e3002632. doi: 10.1371/journal.pbio.3002632. PMID: 38768403; PMCID: PMC11105162.



Just to add - I think that Cnidaria and Bilateria are more closely related to each other than they are to Ctenophora. This is because Ctenophora does not have the other neurotransmitters - it uses only l-glutamate. Also, Cndiarians seem to have rudimentary eyes controlled by Pax6, but ctenophores do not.
